# Enforcing Total Participation in a One-To-Many Relationship on the one sided entity? | SQL

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am in the process of translating the following ER diagram into SQL code:

[image]

To model this, I created a table for each respective entity as well as a table for the relationship. My problem is modelling the one-to-many relationship as well as enforcing the total participation constraint on the *Medical Test* entity.

I begin with the *Person* entity:

```
-- Person Entity
CREATE TABLE Person (
uniquePersonID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
gender CHAR(1),         -- "M" = Male | "F" = Female
firstName VARCHAR(30),
lastName VARCHAR(30),
dateOfBirth DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (uniquePersonID));
```

I assign the ID as NOT NULL because it is a primary key.

Followed by the *Medical Test* entity:

```
CREATE TABLE MedicalTest (
testID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
testFee REAL,
testName VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (testID));
```

Now comes the part where I am struggling with, the *Does Test* relationship:

```
-- Does Test Relationship
CREATE TABLE DoesTest (
uniquePersonID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
testID CHAR(10),
testDate DATE,
result VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (testID),
FOREIGN KEY (uniquePersonID) REFERENCES Person,
FOREIGN KEY (testID) REFERENCES MedicalTest);
```

From what I have learned, if for instance, I want to make *Medical Test* have total participation, I make the *Patient* Primary Key be NOT NULL. To model the one-to-many, I assign the primary key to the one side entity. However, when I run the file, it tells me *testID* in the relationship table can not allow NULL values. However, from what I have been taught, if I assign it NOT NULL, that would force it to have total participation, something I am trying to avoid.

The error:

```
CREATE TABLE DoesTest ( testDate DATE, result VARCHAR(100), testID CHAR(10), 
uniquePersonID CHAR(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (testID), FOREIGN KEY 
(uniquePersonID) REFERENCES Person, FOREIGN KEY (testID) REFERENCES 
MedicalTest)
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0542N  The column named "TESTID" cannot be a column of a primary key or 
unique key constraint because it can contain null values.  SQLSTATE=42831
```

Comment: What's the database engine? DB2? Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Comment: The engine is DB2.

Comment: Use `DECIMAL` or `DECFLOAT` for monetry amounts, not the binary floating point you have here `testFee REAL`

Comment: You ave lots of NULLable colums. It it really vaild (for example) for a `MedicalTest` not to have a `TestName`. Aso should `TestName`s not be unique?

Comment: P.S. you need to double quote all your identifires if you want to keep your mixedCase naming standard

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the double quoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key of a table NEVER accepts null values, and should always include the `NOT NULL` constraint.

It should work if you change your primary key to:

```
CREATE TABLE DoesTest (
  testDate DATE,
  result VARCHAR(100),
  testID CHAR(10) NOT NULL, -- added NOT NULL here.
  uniquePersonID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (testID),
  FOREIGN KEY (uniquePersonID) REFERENCES Person,
  FOREIGN KEY (testID) REFERENCES MedicalTest
);
```

I don't get exactly what you mean by "total participation" but the `NOT NULL` constraint is validated only for existing rows. Not all patients must have a corresponding row in `DoesTest`. Those would model patients who haven't yet taken the test, and that's perfectly normal.

Comment: By total participation, I mean that a medical test must be in a relationship with a patient which is indicated by a thicker black line, the arrow determines that it is a many-to-one. By forcing testID to be NOT NULL as well, I have been told this makes the Patient entity have total participation as well, something I don't want happening.

Comment: No, adding `NOT NULL` in the table `DoesTest` will not mandate total participation for the Patients. `uniquePersonId CHAR(10) NOT NULL` will enforce the test belong to a patient, but the patient is not forced to have a test. I think this is what you want.

Comment: If assigning NOT NULL will not mandate total participation, what will? As it is required for Medical Test. Also, have I correctly represented the one-to-many relationship?